# How can I print a right/left angle character without using ">" and "<" symbols?

Tags: symbols, characters

Please, don't ask why I need this. I need to print `>` character, but I can't use the `>` symbol inside the `.tex` file. `\rangle` doesn't work for me, since it prints a math-mode char, which looks very much different from `\texttt{>}` (I need true-type font).

Comment: `\chardef\myrangle=62 \texttt{\myrangle}`

Comment: Now that I answered, I can ask *why*.

Comment: @egreg thanks for your help, here is why: https://github.com/yegor256/naive-ebnf/commit/31b54e8fb775a5268a68a3e233224f5f10f6bf80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\textgreater` works with any encoding (in text mode); remember that TeX will ignore spaces following the command, so you may need `\textgreater{}` if a space must follow.

If you also need to use `>` in math mode (but cannot input the character), also do

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathgreater}{\mathrel}{letters}{"3E}
```

or, more simply but more cryptic,

```
\mathchardef\mathgreater=\mathcode62
```

Comment: There is also `\textless`

Comment: apparently, `\texttt{\textgreater}` and `\texttt{>}` look differently, do you know why and how to fix?

Comment: @yegor256 You need `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` if you need `\textgreater` in typewriter type.

Answer (score 1):

When compiling with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you can use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\chardef\myrangle=62
\chardef\mylangle=60

\begin{document}
\mylangle\myrangle
\end{document}
```

(in pdfLaTeX you'll need to also `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`).

This'll give the following output:

[image]